# Hadoop: How to create an auto-increment id

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, auto-increment

I need the SQL equivalent of an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id in hadoop.

When my reduce task identifies a new item, those items needs a unique ID assigned.

- How can I share an atomic counter across the cluster? The reporter
  counters seem to be just increment counters, there's no
  getAndIncrement feature that I see.
- How can I set that counter before the map/reduce phase of the job
  starts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Distributed sequence number generation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671858/distributed-sequence-number-generation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform distributed id generation you can either just generate uuids or use functionality found in [Apache Zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/), which can do distributed coordination on Hadoop clusters.  Disclaimer: I have never used Zookeeper, so I don't know if you can really (even theoretically) get a global contiguous set of ids, which is what the question *seems* to be asking.

Generating UUIDs does have a cost, though; they take some time to generate.

For good general information on distributed ID generation, see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671858/distributed-sequence-number-generation).

Comment: Yeh, they have to be incrementing ID's in a specific range not just unique.

Comment: I thought that is what you wanted.  Check out zookeeper then.  While I've done a lot with hadoop, I've always generated UUIDs because the very thought of building in a global atomic integer just seemed weird.  On a 1,000 node cluster you want 999 machines to wait?  Seriously, I expect that the Zookeeper people figured this all out, however intractable it seems.  If you can't get what you want, generate uuids in the map phase then create a contiguous set in the reduce phase, or in a separate sequential process _after_ your MR jobs complete.